# Load Multi-dimensional Mat from Text File using cv::FileStorage

Tags: c++, opencv

I have successfully saved a Mat of size(10,10, CV_32F24) to a text file using cv::FileStorage. However, when I try loading/reading it again using cv::FileStorage it fails and gives me the error below:

**Error thrown:**

"Unhandled exception at at 0x000007FEFD7D940D in CRF_6Epochs_d.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000000015C3D0".

**Error shown in console:**

"OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (Too complex format for the matrix) in unknown function, file ......\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp, line 3106"

My code is as shown below:

```
const char *Path = "J:\\DATA\\WorkDIR\\AOI\\MultiEpochs\\54By54KM2\\Nodes\\Test.txt";
FileStorage saveNode(Path, FileStorage::WRITE);
saveNode << "NodePot" << fv1;
saveNode.release();

FileStorage loadNode(Path, FileStorage::READ);
Mat N(imgSize.height, imgSize.width, CV_MAKETYPE(CV_32F,24));
if(!loadNode.isOpened()){
    throw std:: runtime_error("Failed to Open File");
}

loadNode["NodePot"] >> N;
loadNode.release();
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I came across the same issue. The problem is that there is an upper limit for the number of channels when you load a Mat from `FileStorage`. A possible workaround is reshaping the Mat to one channel like so:

```
saveNode << "NodePot" << fv1.reshape(1);
```

And then reshaping it back to the desired number of channels:

```
loadNode["NodePot"] >> N;
N = N.reshape(24);
```

You could also save the number of channels in the `FileStorage`, if it's not fixed anyway.

```
saveNode << "Channels" << fv1.channels();
int channels = (int)loadNode["Channels"];
```

Answer (score 0):

from my knowledge you can only save data from opencv into xml and yaml files. so change your Test.txt to xml pt yaml file.

Comment: errm, nope, - anything not explicitly named ***.xml will get saved as yaml. (please try out yourself , before posting)